# Destructuring objects with typescript

Tags: typescript, destructuring

I'm trying to add types to the destructured variables however they are still returning `any`.

**Questions:** How can I add types while destructing?

```js
  export interface TableReturnState {
    status: number;
    data: APIOrders[];
    columns: [] | JSX.Element[];
    sort: Function;
  }

  const { data, sort, columns, status }: TableReturnState = useTableHook(
    configuration
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that's not the way to do it.

You don't decide what useTableHook returns, it's on the useTableHook to say what it returns. Destructured items will then have their correct typings.

Something like this :

```
useTableHook = (configuration: Configuration): TableReturnState => ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example works fine for me.
But you can try:

```
interface TableReturnState {
  status: number;
  data: APIOrders[];
  columns: [] | JSX.Element[];
  sort: Function;
}

function useTableHook(config: TypeOfConfig): TableReturnState {
  // Your code
}

const { data, sort, columns, status } = useTableHook(configuration);
```